# Adding android.jar as a dependency for a module in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I have decided to ask the question after my research did not reveal any useful solutions for my scenario which I believe should be quite popular.

My question is slightly related to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154681/android-studio-java-library-module-vs-android-library-module/28155942?noredirect=1#comment52222797_28155942), but the solution did not help in my scenario.

I want to create a Java module that will contain only my application logic. That said, I do not want it to be an Android Library module. I do not need to have manifest files and others for such a library. There will not be any Android activities in my application logic Java module. All Android-specific code will be in the Android module (called *app*). My Java module is called *applogic*.

So technically, I want my project to look like

```
AppProjectName
|-->app //Only Android-specific code here
   |
   -->src
|-->applogic //General, reusable Java-code here
   |
   -->src
```

In the *app* module settings, I add *applogic* as a module dependency.
From my Android *app*, I create objects defined in classes in *applogic*. I am able to do that easily.

And here is the thing. I want to use Android's logging capabilities (in `android.util.Log`). How can I use that for my Java library?

A possible solution that was stated in the SO question mentioned above was to add `android.jar` as a library to my `applogic` module. I was not able to do that in Android Studio. Any guidance will be greatly helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: "I do not want it to be an Android Library module" -- why? "I do not need to have manifest files and others for such a library" -- so? "There will not be any Android activities in my application logic Java module" -- so? If you had just used an Android library module, and paid the price of a nearly-empty manifest file, you would have been done by now.

Comment: @CommonsWare Good points, but the *applogic* Java module needs to be portable. I may plan to use it elsewhere. I will have flags around my Android-specific code, like `Log.v()`. If I want my library to be just a Java library, there must be a way to be able to use some Android APIs by including `android.jar`. What do you think?

Comment: "but the applogic Java module needs to be portable" -- so? Create a JAR out of the Android library module.

Comment: I gave your suggestion a try. I created an Android Library called *myapplib*. This needs to be a dependency for the Android *app* module. From the Module settings, I am not able to add *myapplib* as a dependency to *app*. The *myapplib* is a work in progress. If you ever encountered the same scenario as I did, how did you go about solving it? Thanks!

Comment: "From the Module settings, I am not able to add myapplib as a dependency to app" -- what are your specific symptoms? I usually just set it up by hand, having `settings.gradle` list both modules, and adding `compile project(':myapplib')` in my app's `build.gradle`.

Comment: "If you ever encountered the same scenario as I did, how did you go about solving it?" -- I would not assume that code developed using the Android SDK will work on any version of the JVM. If I wanted a portable JAR, I would create a portable JAR compiled against a JVM. For anything where I wanted to do Android-specific stuff related to the library, I would use interfaces and such to allow the hosting code (e.g., the Android app) to supply implementations that do the Android-specific stuff (e.g., logging to LogCat), so the library is Android-free.

Answer (score 5):

If you're running within the context of a project created by Android Studio, you'll have a `local.properties` file giving the SDK location. Even if you're haven't got such an auto-generated file, there's nothing stopping you from creating it. It looks something like this:

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Tue Apr 04 12:34:41 BST 2017
ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\smith\\Programs\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\smith\\Programs\\android-sdk
```

Either way, you can then use it in what I assume is the same manner as the Android Gradle plugin does:

```
dependencies {
    Properties localProps = new Properties()
    localProps.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    implementation files("${localProps.getProperty('sdk.dir')}/platforms/android-15/android.jar")
}
```

Of course, you'll have to make sure you've downloaded the appropriate version of the platform using the Android SDK Manager, but if you're an Android developer you've probably already done that.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same setup for one of my projects. I'm using `android.util.Log` and `android.os.Build` classes in a Java Library module.

In your *app* module, you should add *applogic* as a module dependency to `build.gradle`, which you have already done.

Then, in your `build.gradle` for *applogic* module, you should add `android.jar` dependency like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
}
```

Since you are using `android.util.Log` which is available since API 1, then you can use any "android.jar" from any SDK Platform. Just copy it to your *applogic* module `libs` folder. Android Studio creates `libs` folder for Java Library modules.

So, your final project should look like

```
AppProjectName
|-->app
   |
   -->src
|-->applogic
   |
   -->src
   -->libs
     |
     -->android.jar
```

Comment: Karim, thank you for this response. Let me give this a try and come back. Actually, is there any other way of doing that without copying the jar file? If my SDK manager updates the SDK, I will have to manually maintain the .jar files.

Comment: Well, your _applogic_ module is no different than any other module. Resolving its dependency on other libraries can be done by either copying the libraries to _libs_ folder, or letting your build system grab them from an online repository. The problem with having a dependency on `android.jar` however, is that the file is not available in any repository. That's why you must copy it yourself from the SDK platform folder.

Comment: You don't need to maintain/update `android.jar` whenever the SDK Manager updates the SDK. You simply use any `android.jar` file that supports the APIs you want to call from your module. Since you need to call `android.util.Log` (available since API 1) then you can use any `android.jar` file. If, however, you want to use `android.util.Base64` class (available since API 8) then you must copy `android.jar` file from Android 2.2/API 8, or higher, since the class doesn't exists before API 8. Once you copied this file, you no longer need to change it.

Comment: I believe this is how Android Studio is doing it, since each module is built separately. When you create an Android Library module and use android-specific APIs, then `android.jar` will be compiled with your module to resolve all dependencies. But when you create a Java Library module, Android Studio does not include `android.jar` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to solve the problem w/o using 'android.jar', but it is very round-about.

1. Create an usual jar module (for example with name 'dummydroid') and add empty implementation of required android API:

   ```java
   // file dummydroid/src/main/android/util/Log.java
   package android.util;
   public class Log {
     public static int e(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) { return 0; }
     //... etc
   }
   ```
2. add the 'dummydroid' module as a `compileOnly` dependency to the `applogic` module

   ```
   // applogic/build.gradle
   ...
   dependencies {
       ...
       compileOnly project(path: ':dummydroid')
   }
   ```
3. That is all. The `dummydroid` object helps to resolve calls to android API during compilation of the `applogic` module. Because of the `compileOnly` type the `dummydroid.jar` is **not** transitively included in the compilation of the android `app` module --- and API references in `applogic.jar` are resolved to calls into the real `android.jar` on device/emulator.

The big shortcoming of this idea is that you have to make dummy implementation of all API those are used in the `applogic`.

Answer (score 0):

Write an interface that mimics the android Log interface

```
public interface LogInterface {
    int ASSERT = 7;
    int ERROR = 6;
    int WARN = 5;
    int INFO = 4;
    int DEBUG = 3;
    int VERBOSE = 2;
    int d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)
    int d(String tag, String msg)
    int e(String tag, String msg)
    int e(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)
    String getStackTraceString(Throwable tr)
    ...
```

Modify your main activity so that it implements LogInterface and add the implementation methods for the LogInterface

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() implements LogInterface {

public d(d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
    return Log.d(tag,msg,tr);
}

public d(d(String tag, String msg) {
    return Log.d(tag,msg);
}
public e(d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
    return Log.e(tag,msg,tr);
}

public e(d(String tag, String msg) {
    return Log.e(tag,msg);
}

public String getStackTraceString(Throwable tr) {
      return Log.getStackTraceString(tr)
}
....
```

Write your own Log accessor class probably storing it in its own java library module:

```
final public class Log {

    private Log() {} // prevent this class from being instantiated

    static private LogInterface logInterface;
      static protected void setLogInterface(LogInterface implementation) {
        logInterface = implementation;
    }

    static public int ASSERT = LogInterface.ASSERT;
    static public int ERROR = LogInterface.ERROR;
    static public int WARN = LogInterface.WARN;
    static public int INFO = LogInterface.INFO;
    static public int DEBUG = LogInterface.DEBUG;
    static public int VERBOSE = LogInterface.VERBOSE;
    static d(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr) {
        logInterface.d(tag,msg,tr);
    }
    ...
```

Initialize the static class in your MainActivity's onCreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    Log.setLogInterface(this)
    ...
}
```

Include the module containing Log class as a dependencies in your java library.  Then in your java library you can use a statement like:

```
 Log.d("myJavaLibrary", "here's a debug message");
```

lazyDen's solution is fairly clever, I think it works and it involves less core writing.  I don't however like the concept of calling android methods
directly from inside a Java library. The android.jar is code that is written to run on top of a properly configured android environment.  When you start using
android methods from inside your java code, you have no guarantees that your android environment is properly setup when you use methods. Probably is,
but who knows for sure. In using the approach that I suggested you don't have to worry whether this is a issue or not.  I would strongly suggest avoiding
Karim's suggestion of adding the android.jar as a dependency to the java library. That seems like asking for problems.